# "Standalone" or "Portable" python modules

Tags: python

I have a question regarding python modules.

For example, I have a script which uses netaddr/paramiko module and now I want to start the script on another linux os where I have no root access. Pip is not installed and the user has no homedir. Virtuelenv is no option.

So is there a possibility/way to 'make' python modules 'portable' and add it to a folder where I can load it in my script??

Comment: you can try pyinstaller. It packages your python script so it's standalone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pip install --no-install` to list the dependencies of the library you need, then copy the modules / packages of all of these libs in your project directory, for example in an `/ext`  subdirectory.